# Tensorflow inference hanging when used with pyzmq

Tags: tensorflow, pyzmq

I am trying to pass predictions made by a Tensorflow model to another process using pyzmq.

I am calling code as simple as `self.model.predict(X)` where self.model is a Tensorflow model.

When I call this line in isolation it works fine. However when I use a client/server architecture where both the client and server are in separate processes and connect to the same socket port as in:

Client:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect(f'tcp://localhost:1234')
...
socket.send_pyobj(X)
...
```

Server:

```
self.model = tf.keras.models.load_model(...)
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind(f'tcp://*:1234')
while True:
    X = socket.recv_pyobj()
    ...
    self.model.predict(X) # <----- HANGS HERE
```

Then this line hangs.

Something else I've noticed is that if I kill the process when it hangs then the port is still in use.

I'm trying to figure out how to debug this as I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the order of `tf.keras.models.load_model(...)` and `socket.bind(f'tcp://*:1234')`

needs to be

1. `socket.bind(f'tcp://*:1234')`
2. `tf.keras.models.load_model(...)`

rather than the other way.